# Inheritance: Base class property accessibility from Derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a kind of confusion here. I have a bunch of classes under mainwindow. One is the base class: `DocumentViewer`. Under this we have multiple subclasses, like `PDFViewer`, `RichTextViewer`, `DocumentViewer`, `ImageViewer` etc.

The property **Borders** which is part of base class i.e. `DocumentViewer`. And `ImageViewer` has the property **AspectRatio**. But as I am inheriting the base class, can I access that **Borders** in derived class and use accordingly for my `ImageViewer` class?

Or I need to create same methods for the `ImageViewer` class too?

```
    class DocumentViewer : public MainWindow
        {
        private: bool Borders;
        public: bool GetBorders();
                void PutBorders(...);
        }
....
....
        class ImageViewer : public DocumentViewer
        {
        private: bool AspectRatio;
        public: bool GetAspectRatio();
                void PutAspectRatio(...);
        }
```

Comment: If the member variable `Borders` is in the `protected` section of the base class, then yes it can be accessed from child classes. That's one of the main points of inheritance, that member variables also gets inherited.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The title asks for the opposite: accesing derived class member from base, while in the question you want to access a base class member in derived

Comment: @tobi303 Yes I corrected the heading. Will try to post sample code..

Comment: @HansPassant Well it was defined like that, now the property is not accessible for images which should have done like you said! Now is there any way or I need to duplicate the properties?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually its in private section, and I have posted the sample code, pls have a look

Comment: Then the member variable itself is still inherited, but it can't be accessed directly from the child classes. Also, having a private member variable and public getter/setter functions means that in all practicality the variable is still "public". Why hide the variable if anyone can get or set its value anyway?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So how can I have the access in Image class, pls provide a sample code to access the Borders variable and set it accordingly for Image class?

Comment: Make the variable `protected` or `public`, or use the getter and setter function you already have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I cannot change the variable access specifiers. How to use getters and setters, some sample code will be appreciated..

Comment: You have the functions `GetBorders` and `PutBorders`. How do you otherwise use them? Perhaps you should take a few steps back, [get a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and more or less start over?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161686/discussion-between-highlander141-and-some-programmer-dude).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you join me for few minutes in the chat room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Borders are no longer directly accessible by the class inheriting `DocumentViewer`, you are still able to modify it using getter and setter that you have declared as in `getBorders` and `PutBorders`. If `ImageViewer` need `Borders`, just access it using getter and setter.

Comment: Can you please add some sample code for the accessing Borders in the Image class?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Some programmer dude's comment, this post provides a helpful answer to the question:

[Inheriting private members in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676443/inheriting-private-members-in-c)