# how did the variables get memory without creating the object

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    private:
    int a,b;

    public:
    void setdata(int x,int y){
         a=x;b=y;
    }

    void show_data(){
         cout<<a<<b;
    }
};

class B: public A{
};

main(){
   B b1;
   b1.setdata(3,4);
   b1.show_data();
}
```

How does `setdata` work even if we don't create an object of class `A` (how did the variables `a` and `b` get memory)? And how was it possible to access the private variables of `A` using an object `b1` of class `B`? I am surprised to see my program working properly.

Comment: You might want to grab a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) to get a firmer understanding of C++ basics. This would give you a more thorough overview than individual SO questions can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++, What does the colon after a constructor mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785612/c-what-does-the-colon-after-a-constructor-mean)

Comment: @DDS What? That one is about mem-initializer-lists, this one is about misunderstanding basics of inheritance.

Comment: Try removing the `public A` in the  `class B: public A{` line

Comment: Class `B` inherits from `A`.  So part of a `B` is an `A`.   When a `B` is constructed, so are its parts.

Comment: Is this a variant of the [*"private members are not inherited"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676443/inheriting-private-members-in-c) misunderstanding? The thing is that everything in `A` is also a part of `B`.

Answer (score 3):

> How does `setdata` work even if we don't create an object of class `A` (how did the variables `a` and `b` get memory)

But the code *does* create an object of class `A`, right here:

```
B b1;
```

Since `B` is derived from `A`, each object of type `B` contains an object (the *base class subobject*) of type `A`.

> How was it possible to access the private variables of `A` using an object `b1` of class `B`

Yes, the object is of type `B`, but the function actually doing the access (`setdata`) is a member of class `A`, and thus has a member's access rights to all of class `A`.

Comment: If so then why can't I access the a and b of A using show_data() with b1(getting garbage values).
#include#include<iostream>

class A {
    int a, b;
public:
    void setdata(int x, int y) { a = x; b = y; }
    void showdata() { std::cout << a << b; }
};

class B : public A { };

int main() {
    A  a1;
    B  b1;
    a1.setdata(5, 4);
    a1.showdata();
    b1.showdata();
}

Comment: @ravikiran Because you never called `setdata` on `b1` in the code you posted in the comment?

Comment: @ravikiran When you declare a class (`class A {...}`), you are defining a type of object. When you create an object (`A a1`), you are creating an instance of that type. 

e.g: Let's rename your class `A` to `Animal` and your class `B` to `Dog`. 

So you have `class Animal {...}` and `class Dog: public Animal {...}`.

Now when you create `Animal tucker` and `Dog buddy`, then `buddy` can do all the things `tucker` can do, because it's also an `Animal`, but `tucker` and `buddy` are different individuals, so when you `setdata` on one, you can't `show_data` on the other.

Answer (score 0):

That's how inheritance is supposed to work: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/inher.htm

In short, you've created an object of type B and you've declared that class `B` inherits from class `A`. That means that an object of type B *is* also of type A, just more specific. The same way a float is a number, while an integer is also a number. A Dog is an Animal, while a Cat is also an Animal.

When you define

`class B: public A
{
};`

that means that class `B` should inherit all public methods from class `A`. `setdata`is a public method, as is `show_data()`

Comment: I'm not sure the int/float/number relationship is a useful analogy here, since _number_ is not a base class.

Comment: Sure, I was not speaking about any specific language in that example, just trying to explain the idea. imo, the int/float/number analogy is just as useful as the cat/dog/animal one.